# Selecting the ID of a row between minus ten minutes

Tags: mysql

I need to select any row that has a timestamp of NOW() minus ten minutes. My table looks like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| desc        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| action      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_added  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_action | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reminder    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_to | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ticket_ref  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| log_number  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| accepted    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| completed   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

so I would need to select id from table where time_action = NOW() - 10 minutes

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure about only matching the _exact_ second? An event at 10:00:00 will show up if you select at 10:10:00.999 but not at 10.10.01.000.

Comment: Yes as I don't use seconds for this table, everything that gets added is :00 seconds so it will always be :00

Comment: Ok, so what you want is an entire minute, 10 minutes back?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running your server on UTC without time zone changes, using DATETIME may give you trouble at DST changes (ie since time jumps an hour, there's no data for 10 minutes back, or there's twice the data when changing back), but this should give you what you need as long as that problem is ok;

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE time_action = FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/60)*60-600);
```

Since your seconds are truncated to 00, the calculation is done on the current time, not on the column, to be able to use index matches for the search.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
time_action = (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
 WHERE time_action = (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTES);
```

Let me know if it will work.

Thanks.